# Grouped events in within an hour in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have in db MySQL the table `SignRegister` where register the access to website area restrected.

E.g.:

```
mysql> SELECT
    id,
    `Sign`,
    `DateSign`,
    `HourSign`,
    `AccountSign`
FROM
    SignRegister
WHERE
`AccountSign` IN ('4041002')
ORDER BY
    `DateSign`,
    `HourSign` ASC;

+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+
| id | Sign | DateSign   | HourSign | AccountSign |
+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 18 | B    | 2015-10-29 | 15:01:34 | 4041002     |
| 16 | L    | 2015-10-29 | 15:03:29 | 4041002     |
| 19 | B    | 2015-10-29 | 17:35:44 | 4041002     |
| 20 | B    | 2015-10-29 | 17:49:22 | 4041002     |
+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+
4 rows in set
```

Now I need for the same `AccountSign` delete the access when they are included within an hour and `Sign` value is not `T` value.

E.g. for `AccountSign` **4041002** I need delete the row with `Id number` 16 and 20:

```
+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+
| id | Sign | DateSign   | HourSign | AccountSign |
+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 18 | B    | 2015-10-29 | 15:01:34 | 4041002     |
| 19 | B    | 2015-10-29 | 17:35:44 | 4041002     |
+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+
```

For select those rows I have tried this query:

```
mysql> SELECT
    id,
    `Sign`,
    `DateSign`,
    `HourSign`,
    `AccountSign`,
    TIMEDIFF(a.`HourSign`, b.`HourSign`) AS strDiff1
FROM
    SignRegister a
JOIN SignRegister ON a.`AccountSign` = b.`AccountSign`
AND (
    TIMEDIFF(a.`HourSign`, b.`HourSign`) BETWEEN '00:00:00'
    AND '01:00:00'
)
WHERE
`AccountSign` IN ('4041002')
AND `Sign` IN ('B', 'L')
AND (
    TIMEDIFF(a.`HourSign`, b.`HourSign`) BETWEEN '00:00:00'
    AND '01:00:00'
)
ORDER BY
    `DateSign`,
    `HourSign` ASC;

+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
| id | Sign | DateSign   | HourSign | AccountSign | strDiff1 |
+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
| 18 | B    | 2015-10-29 | 15:01:34 | 4041002     | 00:00:00 |
| 16 | L    | 2015-10-29 | 15:03:29 | 4041002     | 00:00:00 |
| 16 | L    | 2015-10-29 | 15:03:29 | 4041002     | 00:01:55 |
| 19 | B    | 2015-10-29 | 17:35:44 | 4041002     | 00:00:00 |
| 20 | B    | 2015-10-29 | 17:49:22 | 4041002     | 00:13:38 |
| 20 | B    | 2015-10-29 | 17:49:22 | 4041002     | 00:00:00 |
+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
6 rows in set
```

In this case I have locate the `ID number` 16 and 20 with `strDiff1` different from `00:00:00`.

Now try the same code with other `AccountSign`, e.g.:

```
mysql> SELECT
    id,
    `Sign`,
    `DateSign`,
    `HourSign`,
    `AccountSign`
FROM
    SignRegister
WHERE
`AccountSign` IN ('4042801')
ORDER BY
    `DateSign`,
    `HourSign` ASC;


+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+
| id | Sign | DateSign   | HourSign | AccountSign |
+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 83 | T    | 2015-10-29 | 06:31:02 | 4042801     |
| 85 | B    | 2015-10-29 | 06:34:49 | 4042801     |
+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set
```

In this case I don't delete on the same `AccountSign` access when they are included within an hour because the first access is sign `T` value.

But when I try select those rows :

```
mysql> SELECT
    id,
    `Sign`,
    `DateSign`,
    `HourSign`,
    `AccountSign`,
    TIMEDIFF(a.`HourSign`, b.`HourSign`) AS strDiff1
FROM
    SignRegister a
JOIN SignRegister ON a.`AccountSign` = b.`AccountSign`
AND (
    TIMEDIFF(a.`HourSign`, b.`HourSign`) BETWEEN '00:00:00'
    AND '01:00:00'
)
WHERE
`AccountSign` IN ('4042801')
AND `Sign` IN ('B', 'L')
AND (
    TIMEDIFF(a.`HourSign`, b.`HourSign`) BETWEEN '00:00:00'
    AND '01:00:00'
)
ORDER BY
    `DateSign`,
    `HourSign` ASC;


+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
| id | Sign | DateSign   | HourSign | AccountSign | strDiff1 |
+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
| 85 | B    | 2015-10-29 | 06:34:49 | 4042801     | 00:03:47 |
| 85 | B    | 2015-10-29 | 06:34:49 | 4042801     | 00:00:00 |
+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
2 rows in set
```

The query locate the `ID number` 85 which is not to be deleted because the first `Sign` is `T` value.

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit #01**

For the `AccountSign` **4042801** in table `SignRegister` I have memorized these access:

```
+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+
| id | Sign | DateSign   | HourSign | AccountSign |
+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+
| 83 | T    | 2015-10-29 | 06:31:02 | 4042801     |
| 85 | B    | 2015-10-29 | 06:34:49 | 4042801     |
+----+------+------------+----------+-------------+
```

In this case the first access for `AccountSign` **4042801** have `Sign` equal to `T` value.

When exists this situation don't  necessary delete the access in within an hour, because `Sign` equal to `T` value.

Comment: "The first isgn is t value"   in the example you show it is B?

Comment: @Thomas: please see **Edit #01** in my first question, thanks-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to WHERE clause:

```
AND
b.Sign IN ('B', 'L')
AND
a.id <> b.id
```

Both "tables" (left SignRegister and right SignRegister) must have the restriction on Sign and records must not be joined with themselves (optional, for convenience).